# android:installLocation="preferExternal" not working

Tags: android

I have `Samsung S5660 Galaxy Gio` phone with API version `2.3.6`, and i haven't got enough space in my internal memory to install an app, so i've set `installLocation`, here is my `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ....
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" 
    android:installLocation="preferExternal">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
....
```

I've read that it will not work on devices pre `2.2` version, but i can't understand why it's not working for me, the log that i'm getting :

```
[2015-06-13 17:40:36] Failed to install ... on device : No space left on device
[2015-06-13 17:40:36] com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: No space left on device
[2015-06-13 17:40:36 ] Launch canceled!
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing an app on sd-card does NOT mean that it will be installed 100% on external storage. It keeps some critical files (dalvik stuff and etc.) on internal memory and moves the rest (application files, databases, caches and etc.) on the external storage.

Comment: app weight is 50 mb, and i have 30mb free space in internal storage, most of app weight is graphical resources, so if you mean that i have no memory for critical files, i'm not sure that it's the case here

Comment: i'm afraid it could be the case :)