# how do I configure a codenameone project to install on external storage in Android

Tags: codenameone, android-permissions

I am trying to get my codenameone application to install to external storage, so I do not need root permissions to debug what is writes to storage, as it does not work on Android, even if it does in the simulator.

First I assumed just having `codename1.arg.android.installLocation=preferExternal` in `codenameone_settings.properties` would do just that, but the application still installs to internal storage even after changing that installLocation to preferExternal from auto.

So I thought perhaps it needs quotes for the preferExternal, and proceeded to give them (`=\"preferExternal\"`) - this gives a manifest build error on the build server, which shows the manifest with double quotes, so the original was the correct form.

From the error report, I saw that

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:required="false" />
```

so I thought perhaps this needs to be required for the install to external storage to actually be possible. I tried adding `codename1.arg.android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE=true` to the properties file like the documentation would suggest, but that fails in manifest merge:

> Merging result: ERROR
>   /tmp/build6786351350686020379xxx/happy2/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:48:7-69 Error:
>       Element uses-permission#android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE at AndroidManifest.xml:49:5-81 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:45:5-106
>   /tmp/build6786351350686020379xxx/happy2/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
>       Validation failed, exiting

Ok, so I thought that is always included, and thus I just need to change the required setting to true, and followed what the documentation says by adding `codename1.arg.android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.required=true` to the properties. This builds, but the actual permission is not set to `android:required="true"`, but remains false.

Using `android.xpermissions` tag to insert the wanted line `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:required="true" />` does insert it to the manifest, but manifest builder gives and error since the default false line will still be there too:

> Merging result: ERROR
>   /tmp/build5902390972256151175xxx/happy2/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:48:3-103 Error:
>       Element uses-permission#android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE at AndroidManifest.xml:48:3-103 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:45:5-106
>   /tmp/build5902390972256151175xxx/happy2/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
>       Validation failed, exiting

So the question remains, **how do I configure a codenameone project to install on external storage in Android**?

Answer (score 0):

See this [android:installLocation="preferExternal" not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30819947/androidinstalllocation-preferexternal-not-working)

The gist is that parts of your app will always install in the hidden area and storage will probably go there.

If you want to write stuff to the SD card you can do that with the `FileSystemStorage` API which allows you to write to arbitrary roots. You can detect the SDCard root and just write there. I would suggest debugging in the simulator though where you can see the content of storage easily in the `.cn1` directory.